# How to use one application for another application in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-intent, android-contacts, android-contentprovider

I have an application created for 3D carousel view using open gl es. I want to display contacts or gallery images in 3D carousel view using the created application. How to approach? How an I use one application as library for another application?

Comment: I think you can only send Intent to them if they accept any

Comment: Right.  This question doesn't make any sense, you can't force another app to be used as a "library" for your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably talking about making another application use your app. This cannot be possible, since you can't really change someone else's application. But you can make your own application that will view Contacts or Gallery data using your carousel view, since contact and media data are accessible using `Content Providers`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to create an application which displays contacts by using carousel application.

Answer (score 0):

Either use code for your carousel as library in current app and access contacts or gallery directly from it or use intents as someone said to provide content to 3D carousel (probably trough some adapter)